# Importing a CSV file containing line breaks in cells into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, csv

The MySQL import script is

```sql
CREATE TABLE `AuxClasses` (
    `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Category` char(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `Section` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `Subsection` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `ClassNumber` char(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `ClassTitle` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/classes.csv'
INTO TABLE `AuxClasses`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 3 LINES
(
    `Category`,
    `Section`,
    `Subsection`,
    `ClassNumber`,
    `ClassTitle`
);
```

The CSV document is actually downloaded as CSV from Google Sheets, which uses `\r\n` line endings, but I ran `dos2unix` on it before doing the import. Some fields within the document contain line breaks, and the resulting import is a complete mess, with fields truncated at weird places, and stray `"` appearing in fields. Does `LOAD DATA INFILE` not understand how CSV linebreaks work? Is there a way around this?

It's also importing (messed up) data from the first three lines, which it should be ignoring. Is it perhaps skipping the three lines *before* parsing the CSV (i.e., skipping three lines of text, rather than three lines of data), and so receiving messed-up data?

Comment: CSV does not support values with inner linebreaks. Replace linebreaks with `\n` literal in the GoogleSheet table data then export - such CSV will be imported as needed.

Comment: What CSV does and doesn't support seems to depend on whom you ask. As I once said to a colleague: CSV is not a file format, it's half a dozen or more different formats in a trench coat.

Comment: But I'll try that; thanks. Most of the linebreaks were in the fields we were trying to skip anyway.

Comment: PS. Linebreak symbol in a cell is CHAR(10) both in Excel and in GoogleSheets.